# loading a UCS-2LE file in Netezza

Tags: odbc, netezza, iconv

I have multiple 30GB/1billion records files which I need to load into Netezza.  I am connecting using `pyodbc` and running the following commands.

```
create temp table tbl1(id bigint, dt varchar(12), ctype varchar(20), name varchar(100))  distribute on (id)

insert into tbl1
select * from external 'C:\projects\tmp.CSV'
using (RemoteSource 'ODBC' Delimiter '|' SkipRows 1 MaxErrors 10 QuotedValue DOUBLE)
```

Here's a snippet from the nzlog file

```
Found bad records

bad #: input row #(byte offset to last char examined) [field #, declaration] diagnostic, 
   "text consumed"[last char examined]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: 2(0) [1, INT8] contents of field, ""[0x00<NUL>]
2: 3(0) [1, INT8] contents of field, ""[0x00<NUL>]
```

and the nzbad file has "NUL" between every character.

I created a new file with the first 2million rows. Then I ran [`iconv`](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html) on it

```
iconv -f UCS-2LE -t UTF-8 tmp.CSV > tmp_utf.CSV
```

The new file loads perfectly with no errors using the same commands.  Is there any way for me to load the files without the `iconv` transformation?  It is taking a really long time to run  `iconv`.

Answer (score 0):

UCS-2LE is not supported by Netezza, i hope for your sake that UTF-8 is enough for the data you have (no ancient languages or the like ?)

You need to focus on doing the conversion faster by:

1. searching the internet for a more cpu efficient implementation than/of iconv
2. Convert multiple files in parallel at a time (same as your number of CPU-cores minus one Is probably max). You may need to split the original files before you do it. The netezza loader prefers relatively large files though, so you may want to put them  back together while loading for extra speed in that step :)

Comment: *"i hope for your sake that UTF-8 is enough for the data you have (no ancient languages or the like ?)"* - For the record: UTF-8 can encode any Unicode character. Some implementations of UTF-8 encoding/decoding have deficiencies (particularly MySQL's "utf8", as opposed to "utf8mb4"), but those are limitations of the implementation, not the encoding scheme itself.